# Disable Close Button using Win32 C#

Tags: c#, .net, winapi, ui-automation, win32gui

I can't disable my application's close button using Win32 in C#. All other application close buttons are disabled via this code:

```
const int MF_BYCOMMAND = 0;
const int MF_DISABLED = 2;
const int SC_CLOSE = 0xF060;

[DllImport("user32")]
static extern IntPtr GetSystemMenu(IntPtr hWnd, bool bRevert);

var sm = GetSystemMenu(hwnd, false);
EnableMenuItem(sm, SC_CLOSE, MF_BYCOMMAND | MF_DISABLED);
```

But my application uses a ribbon control, and its close button can't be disabled via this code. I tried other ribbon control applications, but still the same issue occurs. Check this UISpy Image Guide, how can I disable this close button?

[image: UISpy Image of application ribbon Control Close Button]

I already tried more than 10 other applications with this code, and it works perfectly fine. Only ribbon control applications are not working (tested in 3 Ribbon Applications).

Comment: Hacking applications that you don't own, using Windows standards isn't 100% guaranteed to work. Some applications just don't to use standard UI controls/menus/captions, etc. and build their own UI.

Comment: `GetSystemMenu()` only works on top-level windows, but a ribbon is a child control.  Try using `FindWindowEx()` instead to drill down the parent/child window hierarchy until you find the close button you are interested in. Assuming the ribbon in question even uses standard HWNDs at all (I don't know if it does). You might have to resort to using UIAutomation interfaces instead to access the hierarchy.